# What is this assembly instruction doing?

Tags: assembly

This is a snippet of an assignment regarding data hazards, but I am struggling to understand what it is doing. words beind `:` are my understanding of the instructions

```
loop:
1.  2, 2, 1  : Add 1 to R2
2.  4, 0(3)    : Load data at R3 address into R4 (?)
3.  5, 4(3)    : Load data at R3 address into R5 (?)
4. SLT 6, 4, 5  : Set R6 = R4 < R5 ? 0 : 1
5. SD 6, 8(R3)     :  Store data in R6 at R3 address (?)
6. ADDI 3, 3, 1  : Add 1 to R3 (?)
7.  2, .  : If R2 == 0, goto 1, else proceed to 8
8. ADD R11, R12, R13.: ???
```

Notes

- initial value `R2 = -2`

Questions

- What is the difference between `0(R3)`, `4(R3)`, `8(R3)`?
- Since initial value of R3 is not provided, how can I make sense of this loop? Only fact I am certain - it runs twice (`R2: -2 -> -1 -> 0`)
- Why is R11, R12 & R13 included here?
- A more general question - I believe this is a RISC-V instruction set. Is there a detailed documentation online to explain these instructions?

Thanks all!

Found this [community-effort cheatsheet](http://blog.translusion.com/images/posts/RISC-V-cheatsheet-RV32I-4-3.pdf), and [IBM docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=set-ld-load-doubleword-instruction)

Comment: The IBM documentation you found is for PowerPC, a different architecture.  Do not use it for RISC-V.  `A(RB)` means “memory at address A + RB where A is a constant and RB is a register.”  This is commonly called an *indexed addressing mode.*

Comment: Since it's an assignment, the instructor should be explicit about the assembly used. CPU architectures vary too much to say anything sane about a general, hypothetical CPU, especially when it comes to things like data hazards.

Comment: As for what the loop does, it's not really important.  You are likely supposed to check for data hazards, not analyse the operation performed by the loop.

Comment: This looks like it could be RISC-V, specifically RV64 where `ld` loads a 64-bit "double word", 8 bytes.  (https://mark.theis.site/riscv/).  So your two `ld` instructions are overlapping and can't both be aligned.  [RISC-V at least by default in the ISA reference allows misaligned accesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748879/risc-v-load-address-not-aligned-to-word-boundary), so that doesn't rule out this actually being RV64 code.  It does mean that both loads in later iterations have a memory dependency on the store from the previous iteration.  Looks like nonsense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the list with what each instruction does:

```
1.  2, 2, 1  : Add 1 to R2 and store the result in R2
2.  4, 0(3)    : Load data at R3 address into R4.
3.  5, 4(3)    : Load data at (R3 address + 4) into R5
4. SLT 6, 4, 5  : R4 < R5 ? R6 = 1 : Do Nothing
5. SD 6, 8(R3)     :  Store data in R6 at (R3 address + 8)
6. ADDI 3, 3, 1  : Add 1 to R3 (?)
7.  2, .  : If R2 == 0, goto 1, else proceed to 8
8. ADD R11, R12, R13.: Add R13 to R12 and store the result in R11.
```

- The number in front of `(R3)` is a temporary offset that is added to `R3` before it is dereferenced. In other words, `LD R5,4(R3)` has the same effect on registers as:

```
ADDI R3,R3,4  ;add 4 to the value in R3, and store the result in R3
LD R5,(R3)    ;treating the value in R3 as a memory address, 
              ;dereference it and store the integer at that address into R5
SUBI R3,R3,4  ;return R3 to its original state.
```

Except this all happens in one instruction and no modification to `R3` actually takes place.

- The initial value of `R3` isn't really important in the same way as `R2` is. `R2` is being used as a loop counter whereas `R3` is being used as a pointer to memory (what it's pointing to, I have no idea).
- As for the relevance to data hazards, the hazard is here:

```
    ADDI R3,R3, 1  : Add 1 to R3 and store the result in R3.
```

Presumably, `R3` is intended to point to a 32-bit integer. This is implied by all the offsets being in multiples of four. For illustration purposes, let's pretend that at the start of the loop, `R3 = 0x40000000`. All the bytes stored at these addresses are made up by me, with the exception of bytes stored at `0x40000008-0x4000000B`, which were written to memory by the instruction `SD R6,8(R3)`. (I'm assuming a big-endian architecture hence the byte order.)

```
0x40000000: 0xDE
0x40000001: 0xAD
0x40000002: 0xBE
0x40000003: 0xEF

0x40000004: 0x12
0x40000005: 0x34
0x40000006: 0x56
0x40000007: 0x78

0x40000008: 0x00
0x40000009: 0x00
0x4000000A: 0x00
0x4000000B: 0x01
```

After instruction 6 in your list executes, `R4` contains `0xDEADBEEF` and `R5` contains `0x12345678`. That's fine, but the problem is we added 1 to `R3` instead of 4. This means that the numbers we're loading into `R4` and `R5` on the subsequent passes through the loop weren't the intended data, but rather junk that was Frankensteined together from different values. Here's what we have after the second pass:

```
0x40000000: 0xDE
0x40000001: 0xAD
0x40000002: 0xBE
0x40000003: 0xEF

0x40000004: 0x12
0x40000005: 0x34
0x40000006: 0x56
0x40000007: 0x78

0x40000008: 0x00
0x40000009: 0x00
0x4000000A: 0x00
0x4000000B: 0x00

0x4000000C: 0x01
```

Here, `R4 = 0xADBEEF12` and `R5 = 0x34567800`. In order to correctly iterate through memory, we need to change `ADDI R3,R3, 1` to `ADDI R3,R3, 4`.

Now why would the CPU even let you do this? Well, some CPUs actually don't, and will fault if you try to write to an unaligned address. Others, like x86, aren't so picky. As it turns out, the CPU *has no idea what type your data is,* and relies on the programmer or compiler to enforce type rules.

Comment: As a pseudo-code expansion for a non-zero offset in a load/store, you could invent a temporary register name to avoid having to explain that R3 isn't ever changed.  e.g. `addi Rtmp, R3, 4` / `LD R5, (Rtmp)` would I think nicely illustrate that there's an addition inside an ALU or AGU (address-generation unit) which isn't written-back to an architectural register.

Comment: If this actually is RV64, `ld` is a 64-bit (8-byte) load.  (https://mark.theis.site/riscv/).  So two loads offset by 4 can't both be aligned.  But RISC-V [at least by default in the ISA reference allows misaligned accesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748879/risc-v-load-address-not-aligned-to-word-boundary).  It also means that both loads in later iterations have a memory dependency on the store from the previous iteration.  Looks like nonsense to me.  Unless it's an 8-bit RISC or something?  But AVR uses flags, not `slt`, and isn't a 3-operand ISA.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fair enough, I was thinking `ld` stood for `load dword` and this was 32-bit RISC-V. I get RISC-V and MIPS mixed up because they're so similar.

Comment: It does stand for "load dword", but a double-word is 64-bit on architectures without 16-bit ancestry (i.e. RISC-V, MIPS, ARM, AArch64).  x86-64 is the only (?) modern ISA where a double-word is 32-bit, because x86 terminology originated with 8086.

Comment: Gotta love the inconsistent terminology. I get it, it's unreasonable to expect every CPU to have the same lingo. Reminds me of `ROL`/`ROR` and how it means something different among various CPUs